# validate password in code or stored procedure

Tags: c#, security, passwords, asp.net-membership

I am currently creating a login and registration system with .net/c#. A sql server database holds usernames and passwords (hashed passwords with a salt etc)

When I need to validate the password, what is the current procedure. Is it to take the value the user has inputted hash it with the salt etc, pass it in to a stored procedure and do a comparison there? Or, same steps as above but do a compare of the passwords in C# code?

I would like to make a decision based upon best practice and the most secure method so looking for suggestions on this and items I should consider.

Comment: I've always given SQL exactly what it needs.  So I salt before passing in -- both for saving and for loading/comparing.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a six and two threes. The important thing for me is that you're not storing the password, but a hash. That's good design.

The only thing I'd add is just to be consistent. Presumably as well as dealing with logins your hash engine will also come into play when users create accounts or reset passwords. Keep it all in the one black box. In other words, one of the database or the c# should be pretty intelligent, the other pretty dumb.

I suppose you could come at it from reusability....any chance you'll want to re-use the security mechanism either with a different database? or without a layer of componentry above it? That might sway your choice.

The only other thing I can think of is what security you're putting around changing data within the app (i.e. day-to-day business function). Might that aspect influence your decision?

Answer (score 0):

Either way would work, but personally I would do the comparison in C# code.

My concern would be that if someone had access to the database, they could simply change the validation sproc to always return success even if the hashes didn't match.  But this really comes down to what you trust more - your application code security or your database security.

Comment: This is true but you could equally come at this from the other direction. If your concern were that someone could access the code and could then just ignore the database response...that's just as valid.

Comment: @PeteH - exactly, which is why I said it just comes down to which you trust more - your code or your database.  I could see reasons why people might go either way on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Ive always done general validation of the username/email then pull password from db using that and compare to user entered value in code... I'm a developer not a dba which makes me of the thought that the database is in support of code(not the other way around) so when a situation comes up like this where speed is not affected I push the logic to code ..

not really right or wrong .. just what I would do

EDIT: Always encrypt/hash your password.

Comment: I would not store passwords in the db. You obviously need to store something but I'd run it through a trapdoor function first. The only question is where the trapdoor sits.

Comment: I thought it was obvious not to store plain text non-hashed passwords. Didn't think that needed to be said.  I thought I answered the question that was asked, to house compare logic in code or in the db.  Anyway I still voted up your answer because it was more complete than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare it using what you know best. Unless you are absolutely sure that there is no way to trick the stored procedure into returning a "True" when the password is wrong, then you'd better compare it in code. I advise you against doing something like " select * from users where login 〓 [value]"

I would rather do:

- sanitize user input (i.e escape unwanted characters that would lead to a sql error or sql injections)
- Prepare a parameterized query or stored proceduere that takes both user and hashed password as inputs.
- Make the sp return  every matching row, and both fields (login and pasword)
- in code, check that the sp returned one and ONLY one row and that both login and password match the user input (avoids some sql injections).

Some of these are somehow redundant, but increase the security anyway.